# DataTable is not a function error with DataTables JQuery library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a simple example of using the Datatable library. I have it working with JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/3hhn7y7f/), but when I try to do it with actual files I get the following errors. I have `JQuery` defined in the `<script>` tag so I don't know what the issue is.

`Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function`

HTML file

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>

 </body>
 </html>
```

script.js

```
var dataSet = [
    [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
    [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
    [ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ],
    [ "Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060" ]
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Position" },
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Extn." },
            { title: "Start date" },
            { title: "Salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? After including jquery it was working fine!

Comment: @varun is jquery this one: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>` if that is the case, am I not linking properly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You likely need to switch the order of the `<script>` tags.

Put this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

BEFORE this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

That is, define jQuery before you define DataTables.

Comment: i am having the same problem can you please view this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566622/bootstrap-table-sorting-filtering-pagination-using-datatable-js?noredirect=1#comment66443792_39566622

Comment: This did not work for me :/