# Bootstrap table sorting, filtering, pagination using dataTable.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on asp.net MVC-5 and created a Bootstrap table to show data 
Now i want to apply pagination, filtering and sorting, for this i searched may articles and found [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/823490/Bootstrap-Table-With-Sorting-Searching-and-Paging), the technique is very simple in this link and it's same to what i am doing in my project. Bellow i have included my `.js` and `.css` files

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-toggle.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-toggle.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/favicon.ico" />
```

Bellow is my razor syntax for table

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th style="color:#006bff; font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif" >
            Name
        </th>
        <th style="color:#006bff; font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif">
            Ocurrence Time
        </th>
        <th style="color:#006bff; font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif">
            Recover Time
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        @{
        if (ViewData["events"] != null)
        {
        if (ViewData.Values != null && ViewData.Values.Count() > 0)
        {
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in (ViewData["events"] as System.Data.DataTable).Rows)
        {
        <tr>
            <td style="border:1px solid black; color:green;font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif">
                <span style="font-size:12px;">@dr[0]</span>
            </td>
            <td style="border:1px solid black; color:green;font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif">
                <span style="font-size:12px;">@(string.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt}", dr[1]))</span>
            </td>
            <td style="border:1px solid black; color:green;font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif">
                <span style="font-size:12px;"> @(string.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt}", dr[2]))</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
        }
        }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

At the end i have placed my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myTable').dataTable();
});
```

Bellow is the controller code

```
//Getting Events from Database
//string query = "SELECT Distinct DE.Occurrence_Time,DE.Recovery_Time FROM Device_Events DE INNER JOIN ADS_Device_Data AD ON AD.Device_ID=DE.Device_ID WHERE 1=1 ";
string query = "SELECT Distinct  e.Event_Name, de.Occurrence_Time, de.Recovery_Time from Device_Events DE inner join Events e on de.Event_ID = e.Event_ID inner join ADS_Device_Data ad on de.Device_ID = ad.Device_ID where 1=1 ";

if (search != "") {
    query += " AND ad.Device_Serial_Number= '" + search + "'";
}

if (time.ToString() != " ") {
    query += " AND de.Occurrence_Time >= '" + time.ToString() + "'";
}


SqlCommand event_command = new SqlCommand(query, con);

//SqlCommand event_command = new SqlCommand("Select Device_Event_ID,Device_ID,Event_ID,Occurrence_Time,Recovery_Time from [Device_Events] where Device_ID=@device_id", con);
//event_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@device_id", device_id);

con.Open();
SqlDataReader reader_events = event_command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader_events.Read()) {
    //events.Add(Convert.ToString(reader_events["Event_Name"]));
    //events.Add(Convert.ToString(reader_events["Occurrence_Time"]));
    //events.Add(Convert.ToString(reader_events["Recovery_Time"]));
    events.Rows.Add(Convert.ToString(reader_events["Event_Name"]),
        Convert.ToString(reader_events["Occurrence_Time"]),
        Convert.ToString(reader_events["Recovery_Time"]));



    //events.Add(string.Concat(Convert.ToString(reader_events["Event_Name"]) + " - " +" Occur " + Convert.ToString(reader_events["Occurrence_Time"]) + " - " + " Recover " + Convert.ToString(reader_events["Recovery_Time"]).Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine)));

    //events.Add(string.Concat(" Power Failure " + " Event ID # " + Convert.ToString(reader_events["Event_ID"]) + " Device ID # " + Convert.ToString(reader_events["Device_ID"]) + " Occur at " + Convert.ToString(reader_events["Occurrence_Time"]) + " Recover at " + Convert.ToString(reader_events["Recovery_Time"]).Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine)));
    //events.Add(string.Concat(" Power Failure " + " Event ID # " + Convert.ToString(reader_events["Event_ID"]) + ", Device ID # " + Convert.ToString(reader_events["Device_ID"]) + ", Occured " + Convert.ToString(reader_events["Occurrence_Time"]) + ", Recover " + Convert.ToString(reader_events["Recovery_Time"]).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 5)));
}
con.Close();
```

After that i have placed the events in viewdata `ViewData["events"] = events;`

After doing all this i got bellow result

[image]

No paging, sorting and filtering is enabled

I must be missing something

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: What is version of your Datatable plugin ? Also if you are using `version > 1.10`  then use  `$('#myTable').DataTable();` instead of `$('#myTable').dataTable();`

Comment: Also, Try enabling the sorting for few columns explicitly and see if it works, Try something like, `$('#myTable').DataTable({order: [[ 3, 'desc' ], [ 0, 'asc' ]]} );`

Comment: @parkash: I have downloaded from this link https://datatables.net/download/    also i have changed .dataTable(); to DataTable(); nothing happens

Comment: @faisal, Please add the headers as stated by @Mannam in table definition. If it does not solve the issue please create the `JSFiddle` of your code.

Comment: @all: i am getting this error 
$(...).DataTable is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use <**thead**> tag in table

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="color:#006bff; font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif" >
            Name
        </th>
        <th style="color:#006bff; font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif">
            Ocurrence Time
        </th>
        <th style="color:#006bff; font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif">
            Recover Time
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: i am getting this error $(...).DataTable is not a function

Comment: did you put the thead tag ?

Comment: @faisal Please check, this issue also occurred when referenced jQuery twice

Comment: @Div: jQuery is added on time only

Comment: @faisal create JSFiddle

Comment: @all there was multiple jQuery includes now it's working fine thanks all :)

Comment: How do you find the other jquery reference? I only included jquery once yet I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but the solution that worked for me was not listed here, and this still appears at the top of the results in Google. Try adding `defer` to your datatable.js import

```
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

if you open developer tools (in chrome) and click on "Network" you can see which order your files are loading. And even though Jquery.js by appear before DataTables.js in your html file, Jquery may not have finished loading by the time DataTables does. adding `defer` ensures that the datatables.js file loads last.

Additionally if you want to know if you are somehow loading two instances of jquery (another possible cause of this problem) you can see that in Developer tools under "Network".

Comment: Was having this issue for quite sometime. Was importing jquery before datatables js but wasn't working. Adding `defer` fixed it! Thanks