# ERROR TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function while using in angular 4

Tags: angular, datatables

I'm getting ERROR TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function while using in angular 4.

[image]

Any suggestions for resolving this issue.

Comment: "*Any suggestions for resolving this issue.*" Yes, include the DataTables library files.

Comment: Please share the steps, how to include DataTables library files

Comment: After adding libraries also. I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: I have literally no experience with Angular 2/4/5, but I would certainly first look at https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started instead of trying to get the naked standalone jQuery version work.

Comment: Try solution given in below URL.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32315701/datatable-is-not-a-function-error-with-datatables-jquery-library

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are importing jQuery as a local lib, in your *component.ts file, like:

```
import * as jquery from 'jquery'
```

remove that line and treat it as a global library:

```
declare var jquery: any;
```

or

```
declare var $: any;
```

or just add one of that two lines to src/typings.d.ts

Comment: Thank you. declare var $: any; helped me with using jquery / datatables in Angular 6.

Comment: Thanks, @Bogdan I was searching this answer on data table site also but any solution over there was not helping your solution did help.

Comment: Thank you. declare var $: any; works with jquery / datatables in Angular 8.2.8.

Answer (score 1):

Still I did not get datable(datatable is not a function) after adding

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Then I added below code also it's working now:

```
import 'datatables.net';
```

If you still did receive an error, try with the below also:

```
import 'datatables.net-bs4';
```

Answer (score -1):

En Laravel agregue "render" en los archivos importados.

Mi app.blade.php

```js
<script src=" {{ asset('/assets/admin/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js') }} "></script> 
<script src=" {{ asset('/assets/admin/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }} "></script> 
<script src=" {{ asset('/assets/admin/dist/js/adminlte.min.js') }} "></script> 
@yield('scripts')
```

Y en mi archivo que importo donde esta mi tabla agrego el "defer"

```js
@section('scripts')
    <!-- DataTables -->
    <script src=" {{ asset('/assets/admin/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js' ) }} " defer></script>
    <script src=" {{ asset('/assets/admin/plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js') }} " defer></script>
    <script src=" {{ asset('/assets/admin/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js') }} " defer></script>
    <script src=" {{ asset('/assets/admin/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js') }} " defer></script>
    <script src=" {{ asset('/assets/admin/usuarios/listar_usuarios.js') }} "></script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Translate to english please :)

Comment: Please use english on SO.