# Angular DataTables: $(...).DataTable is not a function

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, datatables, angular-datatables

**Angular Version: 6.0.4 ~ Node Version: 10.4.1 ~ NPM Version: 6.1.0**

I've seen this question asked many times, but not answered.

After following these [instructions to install angular-datables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started), and trying to use the directive on a table, as in their [Zero Configuration example](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/zero-config), I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
> at angular-datatables.directive.js:42

**Included Styles and Scripts**

```json
"styles": [
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
   "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css",
   "src/styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
   "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
]
```

**Import in app.module.ts**

```js
import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';
```

DataTablesModule is added to array of imports.

***.component.html**

```html
<h1>View Accounts</h1>
<table class='table table-dark text-center table-striped table-hover rounded' datatable>
  <thead class='thead-dark'>
    <tr>
      <td>#</td>
      <td>Account Name</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor='let account of db.accounts; let i = index' routerLink='/account/{{account.id}}'>
      <td>{{i+1}}</td>
      <td>{{account.accountHolder}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is the order of your scripts correct?

Comment: As in jquery then datatables, yes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619179/error-typeerror-datatable-is-not-a-function-while-using-in-angular-4

Comment: I am not importing jquery in the component.ts as I am not manually calling the function.

Comment: Are you using angular 2 or AngularJS?
Can you share your typescript code please?

Comment: Version 6.0.4. According to the example I followed, there was nothing to add to the ts file of the component, only to add `datatable` to the table in the html. Would you like me to add the section of the installed directive file where it says the error is?

Comment: @Debojyoti I've updated my question.

Comment: What if you manually call $('table').DataTable() from your component, instead of using the html directive?

Comment: Ok, it looks like your node version is little outdated.
Try to update it and then install all the packages in your angular app.
@KayronDeacon

Comment: @David `jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__(...).DataTable is not a function`

Comment: @Debojyoti My Angular version is 6.0.4. My Node version is 10.4.1. And NPM version 6.1.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error was fixed by doing a refresh of my node modules

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm cache clear
npm install
```

I likely had two versions of jQuery installed, resetting my jQuery instance after datatables had bound to it.

Comment: Thanks it works like charm. for windows `rd /s /q "path"`

Answer (score 0):

```
    Angular version(9 and above):
    
    component.ts
    ------------
    import * as $ from 'jquery';
    import 'datatables.net';
    import { from, Subject } from 'rxjs';
    
    export class testComponent implements OnInit {
      dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
      dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();
      
    }

component.html
--------------
 
 <table  [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" id="example" datatable  class="row-border hover">
     <thead><tr><th></th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>....</tbody>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing '        "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
'
in angular.json
It should look like

```
"scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I added 2 links in index.html and that solved my problem

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```